# Opening a .csv file in spyder IDE

Tags: python

I am importing a file with the extension csv and reading the rows to make a list.

```
import csv
with open("passwords.csv") as csvfile:
     reader = csv.reader(csvfile) 

     newList = []
     for row in reader:
         for i in row:
             nrwList.append(i)
```

With the IDE Spyder, I have opened passwords.csv in one of my tabs. When I run the program, it gives me an error saying no such file or directory.

Comment: Your file needs to be in the same directory as your Python script. Tabs in an IDE don't mean anything

Answer (score 0):

Two actions:

Provide the full path: `home/user/....../passwords.csv` or define the directory path in Spyder (preferences)

Then:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv("home/user/....../passwords.csv", sep=',',header=0)
```

Comment: Let's say if I wanted to ask the user for the file through an input, how would the directory work?

Comment: dir=input("Specify the directory"). Then `pd.read_csv(dir, sep=',',header=0)`